# how to call file with a dict and pass it to class object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to call one Object (of class 'Configurator') with a number of dict-entries. The call is from command line. So I expected to do like below. But it seems not to work. 
Is there a major mistake in design?

1st file:

initiator.py

```
from configurator import Configurator

def program1(**kwargs):
    sampleInstance = Configurator(kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kwargs = dict([arg.split('=', maxsplit=1) for arg in sys.argv[1:]])
    program1(kwargs)
```

2nd file:

configurator.py

```
class Configurator:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
```

Input:

```
python .\initiator.py myValue1="Hello", myValue2="World"
```

Output:

```
program1(kwargs)
    TypeError: program1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Use `Configurator(**kwargs)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
from configurator import Configurator
import sys

def program1(**kwargs):
    sampleInstance = Configurator(kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kwargs = dict([arg.split('=', maxsplit=1) for arg in sys.argv[1:]])
    program1(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Should the call to `program1` be using `**`?

Comment: yes. you can pass multiple named parameters to program1.
Like here python .\initiator.py myValue1="Hello", myValue2="World"
myValue1 and myValue2 are two named parameters for program1.

Comment: Um I meant this line: `program1(kwargs)`

Comment: Ohh now i got .. Even i was also missing **. Updated the answer. Thanks